# How to maintain integer values in dynamically linked sliders?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to use a pair of sliders to set integer values for two variables **nLo** and **nHi**, each of which can individually range from 1 to 100, but subject to the restriction that **nHi >= nLo**.  So I set up a slider for each variable that has a range that depends dynamically on the other variable:

```
nLo = 1; nHi = 100;
Column[
 {
   Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[nLo], {1, Dynamic[nHi], 1}, 
           Appearance -> "Labeled"], "nLo", Left
   ],
   Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[nHi], {Dynamic[nLo], 100, 1}, 
           Appearance -> "Labeled"], "nHi", Left
   ],
   Dynamic[{nLo, nHi}]
 }
]
```

The problem is that as soon as I adjust **nHi**, its value becomes real (displays with a decimal point) rather than integer.  I presume that this is because the slider for **nHi** can't tell that its first range argument **Dynamic[nLo]** is actually an integer and so it defaults to real values instead.  Any suggestions as to how to force **nHi** to remain integer valued? (Linux Mathematica v8.0.1)

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you could do something like

```
nLo = 1; nHi = 100;
Column[{Labeled[
   Slider[Dynamic[nLo], {1, Dynamic[nHi], 1}, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"], "nLo", Left], 
  Labeled[Slider[
    Dynamic[nHi, (nHi = Round[#]) &], {Dynamic[nLo], 100, 1}, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"], "nHi", Left], 
  {Dynamic[nLo], Dynamic[nHi]}}]
```

Comment: +1 It's good to know that this use of the second argument of `Dynamic` is explained in the Dynamic tutorial at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html in the appropriately titled section "The Second Argument of Dynamic".

Answer (score 3):

Either I fail to understand the requirements of the solution, or this code may only function correctly in *Mathematica* 7.

---

Interesting problem.  This appears to work:

```
nLo = 1; nHi = 100;
Column[{Labeled[
   Slider[Dynamic[nLo], {1, Dynamic[nHi], 1}, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"], "nLo", Left], 
  Labeled[Slider[
    Dynamic[nHi], {Dynamic[Unevaluated@Round@nLo], 100, 1}, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"], "nHi", Left], 
  Dynamic[{nLo, nHi}]}]
```

Comment: @Leonid I didn't/don't have much time for this, but the sliders appear to be linked for me.  Perhaps I misunderstand.

Comment: @Leonid, I took another look at this, and I still don't see where it fails.  It annoys me that I can be this blind; would you please try again to explain how my solution is functionally different from Heike's?

Comment: **It appears that I was wrong and the solution works perfectly. Sorry for that. +1**